# Avoiding same installed programs which repeated in two times installed programs

Tags: inno-setup, labview

I made the installer from LabVIEW for my application. Using this LabVIEW installer, I made another exe file that contains all files from LabVIEW installer with the help of [Inno setup compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJqzQ.png). Reason for this, I need a single file installer to attach the digital signature. So, I used the [Inno setup compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJqzQ.png) and I got the single exe file.

But the problem I faced here, when I am installing this exe file(generated from Inno compiler), I can see the two installer files in the program list window.
one is from LabVIEW installer and another one is Inno Setup installer.

How can I avoid Inno setup installer?

Inno setup code:

```
#define MyAppName "My Product Name"
#define MyAppVersion "4.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Company Name"
#define MyAppURL "https:/<Mydomain.com>/"
#define MyAppExeName "setup.exe"

[Setup]
SignTool=DigiSign $f

AppId={{02A34D16-B816-44B4-AFD6-C620DE6C3D85}

AppName={#MyAppName}

AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}

AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}

AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}

AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}

AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}

DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}

DisableProgramGroupPage=yes

OutputDir=<output directory>\SetupFiles

OutputBaseFilename=My app name_4.0.2006162255 

Compression=lzma

SolidCompression=yes

WizardStyle=modern

RestartIfNeededByRun=no

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "<source file path where LabVIEW installer available>\*"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\<Path for extraction>"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"

[Run]
Filename: "{userappdata}\..path .. where.. I .. want to install it...\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}";
```

[image: Control panel : Uninstall program window]

Comment: Inno Setup creates an installer, so you can't avoid that being there. If you're also running another separate installer, it will also appear and you can't stop it. What you're expecting to happen will never be reality.

Comment: See [Use Inno Setup UI as a self-extractor only - No installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51814408/850848).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uninstallable=no
```

I supposed to use this command in the Inno setup. This resolved my issue. 
For more information visit this [link](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/)

Comment: That's the first step only. But it will leave the LabVIEW installer behind in the "Program Files" folder. For a complete solution, see the link I've posted at your question.