# How to handle DotNet prerequisite with Inno Setup Install / DswinDs system?

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, prerequisites

I have an understanding now of how to use this **DswinsHs** for **downloading** a file (as we have it working for my help documentation).

But now I need to **migrate** some old code that **optionally** downloaded and installed **Dot Net Framework**.

## Old Code

I have this code (used ISTool DLL):

```
const
  // Changed to 4.6.2 download link (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#redist)
  dotnetRedistURL = 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=780600';

function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
 IsInstalled: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  dotNetNeeded := true;

  // Check for required netfx installation
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#net_b
  if(Is64BitInstallMode()) then begin
    if (RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release')) then begin
      RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', IsInstalled);
      if(IsInstalled >= 378675) then begin
        dotNetNeeded := false;
        downloadNeeded := false;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else begin
    if (RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release')) then begin
      RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', IsInstalled);
      if(IsInstalled >= 378675) then begin
        dotNetNeeded := false;
        downloadNeeded := false;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if(dotNetNeeded) then begin
    if (not IsAdminLoggedOn()) then begin
      Result := ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_NeedAdminRights}');
    end
    else begin
      dotnetRedistPath := ExpandConstant('{src}\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
      if not FileExists(dotnetRedistPath) then begin
        dotnetRedistPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
        if not FileExists(dotnetRedistPath) then begin
          isxdl_AddFile(dotnetRedistURL, dotnetRedistPath);
          downloadNeeded := true;
        end;
      end;

      if (downloadNeeded) then begin
        if (MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_NeedToDownload}'), mbConfirmation, MB_OKCANCEL) = IDCANCEL) then begin
          Result := ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_InstallAborted}');
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  // AJT v19.0.0 We always delete the existing local help file if it exists.
  // The new version will be downloaded on the next wizard form if
  // the user still wants the local help. ("downloadhelp" task selected).
  if (bDownloadHelpDocSetup) then DoDeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\CommunityTalks.chm'));

 end;
```

Then I have:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  hWnd: Integer;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) then
  begin
    hWnd := StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{wizardhwnd}'));

    // Don't try to init isxdl if it's not needed because it will error on < ie 3
    if (downloadNeeded) then begin
      isxdl_SetOption('label', ExpandConstant('{cm:Downloading}'));
      isxdl_SetOption('description', ExpandConstant('{cm:DownloadingInfo}'));
      if (isxdl_DownloadFiles(hWnd) = 1) then begin
        if (dotNetNeeded = true) then begin
          if Exec(ExpandConstant(dotnetRedistPath), '/quiet', '',
                 SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then begin
            // handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
            if not (ResultCode = 0) then begin
              // Microsoft present an array of options for this. But since
              // The interface was visible I think it is safe to just say
              // that the installation was not completed.
              MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_InstallFailed}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
              Abort();
            end;
          end
          else begin
            // The execution failed for some reason
            MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
            Abort();
          end;
        end;
      end
      else begin
        // The user most likely cancelled the download of the file
        MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_DownloadFailed}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Abort();
      end;
    end;
    end;
end;
```

That needs changing.

---

## How it is done with DswinsHs

For my download that does work with DwinsHs I basically have **two bits** as follows:

- `[Files]` section:

```
    ; AJT v19.0.0 Download Help Documentation Setup file.
    ; This is associated with the "downloadhelp" task.
    ; It will be downloaded from the internet and deleted after install.
    Source: "{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe"; \
        DestDir: "{app}"; \
        Flags: external deleteafterinstall; \
        Tasks: downloadhelp; \
        Check: DwinsHs_Check( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'), '{#HelpDocSetupURL}', \
                'My_Setup', 'Get', {#HelpDocSetupFileSize}, 0 )
```

- `[Run]` section:

```
    ; AJT v19.0.0 Installed the downloaded help documentation.
    ; This is only done if the "downloadhelp" task was selected.
    Filename: "{app}\HelpDocSetup.exe"; \
        Parameters: "/SP- /VERYSILENT /InstallPath=""{app}"""; \
        WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
        Flags: waituntilterminated runhidden; \
        Description: "{cm:InstallingHelpDescription}"; \
        StatusMsg: "{cm:InstallingHelpStatusMessage}"; \
        Tasks: downloadhelp
```

---

## The issue

I need to convert my previous code (DotNet prerequisite) into suitable file / run script lines (except this time I have to pass 0 for the file size as I do not know the size).

In short, my setup requires admin privileges, and technically, we need it to download and install dotnet (if it is not there) **before** continuing with the setup. The reason being we have these **run** entries:

```
Filename: "{dotnet40}\regasm.exe"; \
    Parameters: "PTSTools_x86.dll /codebase"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: runhidden

Filename: "{dotnet4064}\regasm.exe"; \
    Parameters: "PTSTools_x64.dll /codebase"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: runhidden; \
    Check: IsWin64

Filename: "{dotnet40}\regasm.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/u PTSTools_x86.dll"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: runhidden; \
    Check: FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools.dll')); \
    AfterInstall: DoDeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools.dll'))

Filename: "{dotnet4064}\regasm.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/u PTSTools.dll"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: runhidden; \
    Check: IsWin64 and FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools.dll')); \
    AfterInstall: DoDeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools.dll'))
```

So having DotNet is a prerequisite for the installer to work. Should I be dealing with this differently?

---

### Am I Doing This Right?

Based on the answer provided and my understanding of the documentation ...

Step 1

In `PrepareToInstall` we check to see if DotNet is needed and cache the result:

```
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
 IsInstalled: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  dotNetNeeded := true;

  // Check for required netfx installation
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#net_b
  if(Is64BitInstallMode()) then begin
    if (RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release')) then begin
      RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', IsInstalled);
      if(IsInstalled >= 378675) then begin
        dotNetNeeded := false;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else begin
    if (RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release')) then begin
      RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', IsInstalled);
      if(IsInstalled >= 378675) then begin
        dotNetNeeded := false;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if(dotNetNeeded) then begin
    if (MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_NeedToDownload}'), mbConfirmation, MB_OKCANCEL) = IDCANCEL) then begin
      Result := ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_InstallAborted}');
    end;
  end;

 end;
```

Step 2

We add a `BeforeDownload` handler. This is where we get a chance to add the file we need to download to the list:

```
function BeforeDownload(): Boolean;
 begin
  if(dotNetNeeded) then
  begin
    dotNetRedistPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
    DwinsHs_AppendRemoteFile( dotNetRedistPath, \
                  dotnetRedistURL, 'My_Setup', rmGet, FILESIZE_QUERY_SERVER );
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

Step 3

We add a `AfterDownload` handler. This is where we perform the install of DotNet.

```
procedure AfterDownload(State: Integer);
var
  hWnd: Integer;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if (State = READ_OK) then
  begin
    if(dotNetNeeded) then
    begin
      if Exec(ExpandConstant(dotnetRedistPath), '/quiet', '',
          SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then begin
        // handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
        if not (ResultCode = 0) then begin
          // Microsoft present an array of options for this. But since
          // The interface was visible I think it is safe to just say
          // that the installation was not completed.
          MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_InstallFailed}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
          Abort();
        end;
      end
      else begin
        // The execution failed for some reason
        MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Abort();
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I am not sure if "quiet" is the right way to go now ...

Step 4

We adjust the CurPageChanged handler:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPage: Integer);
begin
  DwinsHs_CurPageChanged(CurPage, @BeforeDownload, @AfterDownload);
end;
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl My help documentation is not a "prerequisite". So it is downloaded "as part of" the installation if the "user wants" it included. But Dot Net as you know is a "prerequisite". This implies that I should be testing if it is needed and if so, install it first and then continue with my setup. I don't know how to shoehorn the code I already have into that equation, compatible with DswinDs.

Comment: Why you cannot install .NET as part of the installation? Do you need it for the installation itself?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, look at "The Issue" at the bottom where we use the dotnet regasm on some of my files to register them.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I see this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752882/how-can-i-install-net-framework-as-a-prerequisite-using-innosetup but  the logic is different for me. Since we are using `{dotnet4064}\regasm.exe` we must install it (if needed) before the rest of our script runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `DwinsHs_AppendRemoteFile` when `dotNetNeeded`.

`DwinsHs_AppendRemoteFile` has basically the same arguments as `DwinsHs_Check` (`DwinsHs_Check` is actually only a `Check`-compatible wrapper around `DwinsHs_AppendRemoteFile`).

I believe that's all you need. The `[Run]` happens only after the download.

Comment: I see. This means we would then have this as the first "run" entry ... So that it is installed first ...

Comment: I am going to accept this because my issue about the actual installing of the framework is another question. Thanks.