# Run secondary setup in background in parallel with main Inno Setup installer

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I would like to add a second installer to my main installer as I also need drivers to install. But I would like it not to launch before or after the main installer but to complete while running in the background and without user interaction. it's possible? (I am on Windows)

All I've managed to do is launch the secondary installer at the end of the main sequence.

Comment: If you run it as a parallel task, what benefit does that have over running it serially? Does it really save a significant amount of time? Is it worth the extra complexity?

Comment: well I would like to provide a "clean" installer that simply installs the program, while the extra drivers install them in the default positions without the user intervening, being indispensable drivers

Comment: @Zamb.S I do not think that explains why you need it to run in parallel.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ok, maybe i misspoke when i talk about running in parallel, what i really want to do is provide the possibility to necessarily install the drivers before launching the main installation.
If possible, I would also like to make sure that these drivers are installed automatically without the need for the user to intervene.

Comment: Then the link in my answer should work for you.

Comment: thanks @MartinPrikryl, I would like to ask you another thing about this, how is it possible to force the abort if the driver installation fails?

Answer (score 1):

*I find it a bad idea overall. What if the parallel installation fails?*

---

Anyway, just see [How can I install .NET framework as a prerequisite using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20752882/850848)

You just need to change `ewWaitUntilTerminated` to `ewNoWait` in the [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) call.