# Using Process Exit code to show error message for a specific File in [Run]

Tags: inno-setup

Using innosetup and want to show error/msgbox if one of the [RUN] process does not return process code 0. I'm using it for authorization process, if authorization is not successful, i want to notify the user.

I have following:

```
Filename: "{pf32}\Common Files\Authorization.exe"; Parameters: " "{code:GetAuthorizationFilePath}" /s"; WorkingDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: skipifdoesntexist hidewizard; StatusMsg: "Authorizing License";
```

Returns me:

```
Process exit code:0
```

0 of course is successful, but if its not 0 i want to notify the user.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks and Regards,
Kev84

Comment: See also [How to force Inno Setup setup to fail when Run command fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1122588/850848) and [Inno Setup: How to Abort/Terminate Setup During Install?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6345920/850848)

Answer (score 9):

I think there's no way to accomplish this from the `[Run]` section. What you can do is:

- use the Pascal Script for this task
- or display the modal error message from your executed application `Authorization.exe` and terminate it only after the user confirms the error message (setup will then continue e.g. with the execution of the other files in the `[Run]` section)

Here is the code sample of the Pascal Script; you can check also the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9621406/2) of this code:

```pascal
[Code]

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
  begin
    Result := False;
    if Exec(ExpandConstant('{pf32}\Common Files\Authorization.exe'), '', '', 
      SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      if ResultCode = 0 then    
        Result := True
      else
        MsgBox('The authorization failed!', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: So i have to create my own function in that [Run] Entry? If so where do I call that function? 

Is there a way to run the method after the process finishes, and if so how do i get the process/error code?

Comment: Sorry for being too late; I'm pretty sure you have resolved this by your own, but still... I've added the example of the PascalScript code along with the [`commented version`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9621406/2).

Comment: If it replaces a `[Run]` entry, setting this code at `WpWelcome` doesn't seem like a good idea. Personally I'd use the `CurStepChanged` function, on `CurStep = ssPostInstall`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same requirements: to run an external program and display an error message if the return code is not 0. It was very important for me to run the program in the `Run` section as I needed to display a status message and the progress bar is nice to have.

I found that you can use `AfterInstall` in the `Run` section to trigger the execution of your program and check the result code (see [this link](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall) for more info about `AfterInstall`.)

So, my idea was to run a dummy program like `change` and to use the procedure specified in `AfterInstall` to run the real program and catch its result code.

```pascal
[Code]
procedure ExecuteRealProgram();
var
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    if Exec(ExpandConstant('{pf32}\Common Files\Authorization.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
            ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
    then begin
        if not (ResultCode = 0) then
            MsgBox('Error! ResultCode is ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    end
    else
        MsgBox('Exec failed! Error: ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    end;
end;
```

```
[Run]
Filename: "change.exe"; WorkingDir: "{tmp}"; \
   StatusMsg: "Running external program. Please wait.";  AfterInstall: ExecuteRealProgram
```