# How can I check if the program was installed correctly using Exec() function in Inno Setup?

Tags: sql-server, exec, inno-setup

How can I check if SQL Server was installed correctly?

I installed SQL Server like this:

```
EXEC (ExpandConstant('{src}\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe'), '/UPDATEENABLED=TRUE /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME='+MSSQL_NAMED_INSTANCE+' /CONFIGURATIONFILE='+ExpandConstant('{src}\setup.ini'), '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Code)
```

Later on I need to do some things (starting SQL Server Windows service, detaching/attaching databases etc.) based on whether SQL Server was installed correctly or not.

Comment: Check the `Code`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: See [Using Process Exit code to show error message for a specific File in [Run\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9621099/850848).