# Error handling in embedded programs on inno setup

Tags: error-handling, installation, inno-setup

I've already spent some time searching on web how to figure this out, but i couldn't.

Does someone knows how to capture when an embedded installation error happens

I need to do something like a rollback when any error occurs.

Comment: You mean `ResultCode` from [Exec function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec)? You may check [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345920/inno-setup-how-to-abort-terminate-setup-during-install)