# How to abort Inno Setup installation in /VERYSILENT mode from [Code] section?

Tags: inno-setup, silent-installer

I'm trying to start a certain Windows service from `[Code]` section (in `AfterInstall` handler). When it fails to start I'd like to rollback installation.

Typically when setup is ran from UI, `WizardForm.Close()` does the job right. But when installer is executed with `/verysilent` command line parameter, `WizardForm.Close` seems to be ignored and installation goes on.
I also tried `Abort()`, suggested by other article on Stack Overflow, but it works just like any other suppressiblemsgbox and doesn't break the installation.

Is there any way to conditionally abort installation in `/verysilent` mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to trigger rollback programmatically.

All you can do is to forcefully abort the installation using the [`ExitProcess` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess).

```pascal
procedure ExitProcess(exitCode:integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';
```

Credits: [Exit from Inno Setup Installation from [code]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438506/850848#7022353).

---

A cleaner solution would be to install the file and start the Windows service programmatically at the beginning of the [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged). And use the [`Abort` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_abort) to interrupt the installation, if something goes wrong. In this context the `Abort` works. See the [function documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_abort).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Abort() because installer first installs service DLLs and then uses the service to publish files, which are installed next. But ExitProcess() works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

WizardForm.Show(); //forcing to show even with verysilent

Comment: How does this answer the question?