# Inno Setup: Calling uninstaller while in setup - is that a proper way to rollback?

Tags: inno-setup

I've got a task to sort out a problem with our product installer and eventually came to a dead end with no ideas.

The installation process goes like:

1. Install files
2. Configure some services in `[Run]` section
3. Run our custom product configurator
4. If step 3 is successful (configurator returned good exit code) then start those services
5. else rollback installation

So the issue was something Shroedinger's - on SOME machines there were unexpected reboot after cancelling install in configurator, without any questions. Of course that annoyed users.

I couldn't figure out the criteria by which the machine decided to reboot, but I stumbled onto this thing:

In `[Run]` section

```
Filename: "stub.exe"; Flags: runhidden skipifdoesntexist; BeforeInstall: ConfigureService
```

Then in `[Code]`, `ConfigureService` calls for `InstallationAbort` proc if configurator returned bad exit code.

Next, in `InstallationAbort`:

```pascal
Exec(ExpandConstant('{uninstallexe}'), '/VERYSILENT /noinstancecheck', '', SW_HIDE,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
```

So the author calls for uninstaller WHILE IN THE INSTALLER.
Using logs I determined, that installation program doesn't end after uninstaller completes work! It's moving to the next step (installation finished)! After that I can see in log

> Restart needed? Yes

Note: system never reboots if configurator is not cancelled, i.e installation finishes the right way.

So what I tried:

- Adding `/NORESTART` to uninstaller `Exec` call. Doesn't help. I think that's because it's installer, who decides to make a restart.
- Adding `WizardForm.CancelButton.OnClick(WizardForm.CancelButton);` and some other calls to exit setup after call to uninstaller. Doesn't help.
- Overriding `NeedRestart` function to return false in case of cancellation

As I tried to understand, author calls uninstaller because of need to delete installed services (i.e. call them in `UninstallRun` with special parameters)

So, my main question: Is that a normal practice to call uninstaller from code called from `[Run]` section, to undo changes made in `[Run]`?

Comment: Show us a full installer and uninstaller log.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a normal practice to call uninstaller from code called from `[Run]` section, to undo changes made in `[Run]`?

In general, it's not a common practice. One should not abort installation in `Run` section. Inno Setup is not designed to handle that.

But if you need to, there's no other way. The code you have is most probably based on this:
[How to force Inno Setup setup to fail when Run command fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1122588/850848#24323119)

But that does not imply that the installer should require reboot. There's some conflict between the installer and uninstaller.